# Changing size and/or aspect of OpenerView in Mathematica 10

Tags: dynamic, options, gui-construction

I would like to change the size of the `Opener` in `OpenerView` when using Mathematica 10. In Mathematica 8, there was the option `Appearance->Tiny` for example that allowed to have a small `Opener`.

In Mathematica 10 this option still exists but is not documented and has no effect, as the default opener seems to have a fixed size.

Is there a way to get the old small MM 8 appearance for `OpenerView` in MM 10 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reported a problem with `Opener` and `Appearance` option, this is the reply:

> [CASE:2678632] Feedback
>
> [...] There is an 'Appearance' issue on the Windows platform and it has been reported already. [...]

So I believe it is a subject to change.

---

As a temp. replacement:

```
opF = Opener@False~Rasterize~(ImageSize -> 12);
opT = Opener[True]~Rasterize~(ImageSize -> 12);

ClearAll[myOpener];
SetAttributes[myOpener, HoldRest];
myOpener[{lbl_, content_}, Dynamic[state_]] := 
 DynamicModule[{fv = Boole[state] + 1},
  Column[{
    
    Row[{
      FlipView[{opF, opT}, Dynamic[fv, (fv = #; state = (# =!= 1)) &],
        ImageMargins -> 0, FrameMargins -> 0], lbl}],
    
    PaneSelector[{
      True -> Row[{Invisible@opT, content}]
      
      }, Dynamic@state]
    
    }]
  ]

x = False;
Panel@myOpener[{"test", "content"}, Dynamic[x]]
```

[image]